# Wine uninstaller not working

Tags: wine, void-linux

I have installed many apps through Wine.

Now, when I need to uninstall an installed app through Wine, normally, I use Wine unistaller. But I don't know why it suddenly stopped working.

When I type `wine unistaller` in terminal, it gives the message:

> ```
> Application could not be started, or no application associated with the specified file.
> ShellExecuteEx failed: File not found.
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a spelling error. It must be:

```bash
wine uninstaller
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that it is just a spelling problem.